# Sum the cells in a Table row using Javascript within an ASP.Net page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I've got an HTML table inside an ASP.Net page, with ASP.Net textboxes
I need to be able to sum all the textboxes ONLY within the table.

I've got a script that does all the textboxes on the page which works fine, but I can't seem to find a way to narrow it down.

I found a script on this site, which identifies the table, and then goes through all the cells, but when I try to implement it, 'cell' is not recognized.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library such as jQuery?

Comment: You have a script? Why not post it here?

Comment: No - I'm not using JQuery - haven't had time to learn it. I've tried creating a script, but nothing works - always errors, so I need to SEE a regular Javascript function which will do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#calculate").click(function () {
            var res = 0;
            $("#table input:text").each(function (i, e) {
                if ($(e).val() !== "") {
                    res += parseInt($(e).val());
                }
            });
            alert(res);
        });
    });
</script>


    <table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt3" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt4" />
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="calculate" value="calculate" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Text="0" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" Text="0" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox3" Text="0" />
```

Only the text boxes inside the table are processed